# How make alert notification

Tags: laravel-5, bootstrap-4

How do I make an alert notification using Bootstrap 4 or Javascript. Here is my code:

```
public function loginprocess(Request $request) {

    $user = Auth::attempt([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password
    ]);

    if ($user) {
        if (Auth::user()->role == UserRole::JOB_APPLICANT) {
            return redirect('/');
        } else {
            return redirect('/admin');
        }
    }else{
        return 'Wrong password or this account not approved yet.'; 
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

It's not good.

Answer (score 0):

Create new notification blade file and try this below code (Note: Please include notification.blade.php in your view file)

```
    @if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span>x</span>
        </button>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <span>{{ $error }}</span><br>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif

@if(session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">        
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span>x</span>
        </button>        
        <span data-notify="message">{{ session('message') }}</span>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: edit ur controller and add : return redirect->back()->withErrors(['message', 'The Message']);